# Large ACCDB file after removing all attachments

Tags: vba, ms-access, attachment

My Access database was originally just short in size of the 2GB limit that Access allows. To reduce size, I went through and removed attachments. Unable to find a good automated way of removing all the attached files, I went through and manually removed each attachment by right-clicking each attachment field, "Manage Attachments", and clicked Remove for all files.

I haven't seen a reduction in my database's size since doing this. Is there a step I missed, perhaps? Is there a macro/query I could run to wipe all attachment data from the table I have?

Please note, I need to keep this field intact, just remove all attachment data. Thanks.

Comment: Have you compacted the database?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the procedure, so no. Will this affect any of my forms, reports, and other VBA code?

Comment: No, compact removes unused space from the db file --- the file size reduction can be dramatic.

Comment: In Access 2007, click Office button, select Manage and then Compact and Repair Database.  If your Access version is different, look around for that option.  Tell us your Access version if you can't find compact.

Comment: Outstanding! I just compacted the database and the filesize went from 1.05GB to 8.4MB. Thanks, HansUp!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2010-specifications-HA010341462.aspx).  You can try putting some of your tables into a separate Access DB and linking them, which will allow you to get around the 2GB limit.  Also, set your DB up to compact on exit, which should help to keep it under control.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Access keeps attachments cache stored in accdb even if you delete records that contains an attachments fields, so you need to make a fresh accdb file, and then import all tables from the accdb you already emptied from attachments

Comment: Access keeps ALL deleted information, including records - even those without attachments. If you do a compact+repair (C+R), then disk space used by deleted rows is recovered. And the SAME occurs for attachments. If you delete the attachments or delete the rows with attachments then C+R will recover that space. In fact most database systems do NOT recover any space until you do a C+R. The reason is simple: if space was recovered then the location of a record on the disk file would change, and that can't work for multi-users. So C+R also requires exclusive (single) user mode use of the file.